# use 'application/octet-stream' mime type in canvas.toDataUrl

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, base64

I have tried using `canvas.toDataUrl` and `canvas.toBlob` to get an base64 encoded string of an image (screenshot).

In both `toDataUrl` and `toBlob`, you can set the mime type as `image/jpeg`, `image/png` and `image/webp`, but can you set it to none, or `application/octet-stream`?

ex.

```
let imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL('applicaton/octet-stream');
```

Whenever I try to do that, it just encodes it with `image/png` mime type.

If it's not possible, how can I get a base64 encoded string of an image with `application/octet-stream` mime type?

Answer (score 0):

The mime-type you pass in these function is a hint for the browser as to which **encoder** they should use to generate an image file.

`application/octet-stream` doesn't correspond to any image encoder and is thus not supported by any browser.

Comment: is there a workaround? as in, perhaps a front end library out there that will encode a blob or array buffer with no mime type, or `application/octet-stream`? i seem to have trouble finding anything. this base64 string will be sent as data to the server and i cannot have the mime type be `image/[png|jpeg]`

Comment: You don't understand... Before you call toDataURL or toBlob, your canvas is just a set of raw pixels with a width and an height => a bitmap. These functions will generate an image file from it. There exists various images file formats. These files will hold binary data, that will have each their own data-structure in order to represent the image. `application/octet-stream` **is not** an image format. There is no way this represents an image. You must know what's the data you want to set in your file before being able to serve it as octet-stream.

Comment: And if all you need is to remove the mime type, then just do `toDataURL().replace('data:image/png;base64,', "");`